# Is there a time-limit on the tweets per account you can query with the Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying te retrieve Tweets from half a year ago using Tweepy and the Twitter API. Accounts with lower tweet frequency are no problem , but more active accounts doe not supply older tweets. The limit changes, e.g. 2 days ago the oldest tweet from a certain account was from February 12 and today the oldest I can get is from Feb 16.

This is not about the limit of tweets per query. I use max_id with the lowest Tweet ID that I have and put the number of tweets per query (count) on 1000.

I also checked the code of Tweepy, to check for hidden arguments, that I missed, But it seems to me like a limit in the Twitter API that is not disclosed.

The Tweet ID that I stored some days ago, but are unavailable know can be used to retrieve the tweets via the browser.

I thought that the rate limit would be the only limit, but know I think that there is a certain number of tweets that can be queried per account.

Does anybody know something about it? Maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of tweets returned for a user timeline is 3,200. Here is the relevant doc

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I knew of this limit, but regarded it as "per query".

Comment: Hey @SFM can you update the question accordingly.